# Error on adding sqllite3 library

Tags: iphone, xcode

If iam adding sqllite3 library to my app it puts following error
Command /Developer/ALI/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

but if I run app on iphone it runs correctly,
please help what is in this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the SQLite library "libsqlite3.0.dylib" in this manner,

Click on the info of "Target->Your Project"->Select General tab->Click "+" button on the bottom left corner ->Select the "libsqlite3.0.dylib" from the list.

If you follow this process then it shouldn't be a problem.

Cheers

Comment: ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in 
ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/ALI/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: So does it give the warning at start up on console or elsewhere?

Comment: see ,now I only added the libaray and it gives error,I have not used database code yet

Comment: Yesterday I used in another project every thing was ok ,it was working on device but error on simulator

Comment: Give a clean build,ie BUILD->Clean all targets,xcode->Empty caches,Delete your build folder in your project and try again.

Comment: Also delete your project from the simulator and try again

Comment: I cleaned all targets empty the caches also deleted the build folder but nothing happend same error is occuring

Comment: Seems strange not seen such thing happen before